# Local directory viewer & Drag and Drop from intranet browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, browser

trying to figure out if there is a way I can embed in a php page (using Javascript, jquery, whatever that will work in a php page) a window that shows a local directory on the computer that the user is on... with the ability to drag and drop files from that window into a waiting jquery uploader on the other half of the page. This jquery uploader requires drag and drop, and to save the user time I'd like to have a local directory tree for them to just grab the folder and drop it on.

Couple things...

- This is an intranet in our own internal network, not accessible outside on the web so I'm not concerned about safety since I know who will be using the page.
- I realize Javascript and jquery don't have the ability to do many local directory functions due to security concerns, which is understandable. So I'm looking if there is a work around with one of those OR some other programming language that can do this.
- EDIT: should also mention that the php file will be running from a server on the intranet, NOT on the user's computer. So the file directory would need to be of the user's local computer.

  So the user logs onto this page, and he's presented with a directory tree so he can drag the entire f:/ drive (for example) that is a thumbdrive with files over to the right side where the uploader goes to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't get a list of files from the user's computer using Javascript because of security.  Any stuff that can be done with local files has to be done via `<input type='file'>` which forces the user to select a file with the browser's "file open" dialog.  You would need to install some kind of client-side component or browser extension to do it differently.  However, a user can open up a Windows Explorer type file browser and select/drag/drop onto the web page a number of files which can be uploaded or manipulated.

Comment: Opening the local file manager was the last option is there's nothing else. I'm trying to eliminate a bit of user error by having it easy for the user to just drag and drop the files into the uploader straight from the browser without having to leave the page and open a file manager window, navigate to the thumbdrive, then drag it over.

Answer (score 1):

Combine this project

Jquery drag & drop: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

PHP Autoindex: http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/

Hope it helps

> EDIT: should also mention that the php file will be running from a
>   server on the intranet, NOT on the user's computer. So the file
>   directory would need to be of the user's local computer.
>
> So the user logs onto this page, and he's presented with a directory
>   tree so he can drag the entire f:/ drive (for example) that is a
>   thumbdrive with files over to the right side where the uploader goes
>   to work.

User's computer should have a shared folder that will be mapped to the server for the server to access the mapped shared folder.

How to map: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6SQJEKCClg

It's an example on mapping, you may want to create another post to ask help on how to map on different environment.

Comment: Does the autoindex show a local computer directory or just local to the server? I realize now I should have mentioned the php page is run from a server on the intranet that the user, on his/her own computer will access.

Comment: I amended the original question mentioning that it's a local computer's files that need to be shown vs the server that the php page is running on.

Comment: You can configure the autoindex script with which directory you want to list.